# What is Material Design's recommended padding for the entire screen background?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

The [Material Design specification](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing) has given detailed metrics for individual components (i.e. Views) but I couldn't find the recommended padding for an entire background layout.

For example, in the following screenshot taken from Material Design Guide, the SearchView is at a distance from the boundary of the background layout, and so will be other Views if/when added to this layout (I guess). So it looks like there is a padding for the full screen background layout in Material Design apps.

What is the recommended value of that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, the padding is added to your project if you use Android Studio to create the project. It's value depends on the screen size. For handheld devices, its value is `16dp` for top/bottom/right/left and for tablets it is `64dp` right/left and `16dp` for top/bottom.

Comment: Where can you find these guidelines for padding? I've found material design guidelines but can't find specific guidance for padding and margins in phone and tablet layouts.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the default activity padding is 16dp, so I guess the recommended amount must be also 16dp. Anyway, it depends on your screen size.

Answer (score 1):

```
="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```